# serialportjs repeats response several times

Tags: node.js, node-serialport

With each request there is one more line. Why is the number of rows increasing?

```
port.write(data.command + "\n");
console.log("command =>", data.command);
const parser = port.pipe(new ReadlineParser({ delimiter: "\r\n" }));
    parser.on("data", (line) => {
      console.log(line);
    });
```

Command and respons:

> command => V
>
> v,4.0.0.0,8f834655363231164c343132
>
> command => V
>
> v,4.0.0.0,8f834655363231164c343132
>
> v,4.0.0.0,8f834655363231164c343132
>
> command => V
>
> v,4.0.0.0,8f834655363231164c343132
>
> v,4.0.0.0,8f834655363231164c343132
>
> v,4.0.0.0,8f834655363231164c343132
>
> command => V
>
> v,4.0.0.0,8f834655363231164c343132
>
> v,4.0.0.0,8f834655363231164c343132
>
> v,4.0.0.0,8f834655363231164c343132
>
> v,4.0.0.0,8f834655363231164c343132

I try to flush port but it doesn't work

```
 port.flush((error) => {
        console.log("port flushed")       
        const parser = port.pipe(new ReadlineParser({ delimiter: '\r' }))
        parser.on('data', line => {
            console.log(line)
        })
    })
```

Comment: When do you add the data listener? Is the first snippet the only code used to create a minimal example?

Comment: I'm receiving a command from Reactjs for a Nest.js backend using Socket.io and I've written it to a port. Then I immediately output the response to the log

Comment: I'm asking where/when/how the data listener is being added. W/o context it looks like the listener is being added multiple times, I've used the Node serial stuff in multiple apps for controlling 3d-printer-like things w/o no similar issues, but that was a few years ago.

Comment: Once only in this file, which is called when receiving a request from the websocket.

Comment: I know what a listener is; you may need to post more context still. The `flush` call is *definitely* not what you’d want to do as shown, and still makes me think the listener is being added multiple times. It may *not* be, but out of context the behavior is suspicious.

Comment: SOLVED! The problem was that I wrote code in an app.service.ts, which created a new instance with a listener with each request. It was necessary to put the code into a separate module and connect it as a singleton. Thanks for the help

Comment: Glad you found it—it happens a lot 